# Running an Executable file from an ASP.NET web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, activex, logparser

I am trying to create  a  web application that can read certain files (logs) provided by the users and then Use the LogParser 2.2 exe by microsoft to parse the logs and provide the requested output.

The idea i have is to run the Local LogParser.exe present in the Users system and then use the same generated output to ready my output.

I don not know if this approach is correct , However i am trying to do the same and somewhere my code is not correctly being followed and i am not able to find any output/Error .

My code segment is as follows :

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LOGPARSER.exe";
            string filename = "LogParser";
            string input = " -i:IISW3C ";
            string query = " Select top 10 cs-ur-stem, count(cs-ur-stem) from " + TextBox1.Text + " group by cs-uri-stem order by count(cs-ur-stem)";
            string output = " -o:DATAGRID ";
            string argument = filename + input + query + output;
            ProcessStartInfo PSI = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName)
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    Arguments = argument,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = false
                };
            Process LogParser = Process.Start(PSI);
            LogParser.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception Prc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Prc.Message);
        }
```

I might be doing something wrong , but can someone point me in correct direction ? Can Javascript ActiveX control may be the way forward ?

All the help is appreciated

(( I am making it as an internal application for my organisation and it is assumed that the log parser will be present in the computer this web application is being used )0

Thanks

Ravi

Comment: So you want users to supply files, which then need to be parsed before uploading to the server?

Comment: Exactly , I will need the log files , that will be parsed using the Log Parser in the Users Local computer and then i will use the output.

Comment: You'll not like the answer, but you should upload the complete file and parse it on the server.  Don't try to automate anything using an executable on the client.  You can't do what you're asking for very obvious reasons.  If it were possible then I could do anything I want on your PC just by getting you to visit my website.  Could you not create an executable for the clients that they run manually and it does the parsing and then uploads the results, all in one process?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to Interop.MSUtil in your project and then use the COM API as described in the help file. The following using statements should allow you to interact with LogParser through your code:

using LogQuery = Interop.MSUtil.LogQueryClass;
using FileLogInputFormat = Interop.MSUtil.COMTextLineInputContextClass;

Then you can do something like:

```
var inputFormat = new FileLogInputFormat();

// Instantiate the LogQuery object
LogQuery oLogQuery = new LogQuery();

var results = oLogQuery.Execute(yourQuery, inputFormat);
```

You have access to a bunch of predefined input formats and output formats (like IIS and W3C)), so you can pick the one that best suits your needs. Also, you will need to run regsvr on LogParser.dll on the machine you are executing on if you have not installed LogParser. The doc is actually pretty good to get you started.